# trying to access a deep value with bracket notation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to record the position of an object that belongs to a row. So in the end I need one comprehensive object that has the row and the position of a "com" inside the row. This is my code: (`g` is a global object)

```
g = {comPos:""}

$(".Com").draggable({
            start: function(event, ui) {
                var thisRow = $(this).closest("div[id^='step']");
                g.thisRowID = thisRow.attr("id");
                g.thisComID = $(this).attr("id");
                console.log(g.thisComID); //returns the id value
            },
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var thisX = event.pageX;
                var thisY = event.pageY;
                var thisComPos = {
                    id: g.thisRowID,
                    x: thisX,
                    y: thisY
                }
                g.comPos[g.thisRowID][g.thisComID] = thisComPos; //undefined
            }
        });
```

This is the error that is being thrown:

```
"TypeError: Cannot set property 'com1' of undefined"
```

Using bracket notation the way I have returns undefined. What am I doing wrong? Please tell me if you need more code, I have pasted the part I thought was relevant.

Comment: I guess we need to see the definition of `g`. What is returning `undefined`, is it `g.comPos[g.thisRowID][g.thisComID]`?

Comment: Can you include the "g" object?

Comment: @JulianD.--g simply contains an empty `comPos`. `g = {comPos:""}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
g.comPos[g.thisRowID][g.thisComID] = thisComPos;
```

it's really a shortcut for looking up `g.comPos[g.thisRowID]`, getting the object that results, and then inserting a new attribute value.  In other words, it's the equivalent of

```
var myTemporaryObject = g.comPos[g.thisRowID];
myTemporaryObject[g.thisComID] = thisComPos;
```

I'm guessing that if you broke down your code like this, then that intermediate "myTemporaryObject" would be null.

Having that intermediate object be populated has to happen explicitly; it doesn't just show up there by magic.

Try something like

```
g.comPos[g.thisRowID] = g.comPos[g.thisRowID] || {} //create an empty intermediate object if necessary
g.comPos[g.thisRowID][g.thisComID] = thisComPos;
```

Comment: @JacobM--I tried your solution and wound up with the same error: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'com1' of undefined"

Comment: @JacobM--the empty object worked, but the downside is that I wipe the row object clean everytime i drag something

Comment: Not sure what you mean about wiping the row object clean -- the idea of using the OR syntax (`g.comPos[g.thisRowID] || {}`) is that if the row object is already defined, it stays, but if it's not defined, we define it with an empty one.  You may want to do the same for defining the g and comPos objects: `g=g||{}; g.comPos = g.comPos||{}`